# Scientific term for someone without any emotions anymore

Tags: single-word-requests

It probably might be emotionless or something but I was born with feelings and I lost them and I don't know what its called. I think I'm just numb. I tried researching it but failed. So all I could find was "anhedonia". It might be the right term but I don't know.

Comment: Sometimes people use "alienated" to describe this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Alexithymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia)

> Alexithymia is a personality construct characterized by the subclinical inability to identify and describe emotions in the self